# Can I use the same account on a different phone?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am playing Pokemon Go; However, I am going to stop using the phone that I use for the app and buy a new one. If I start playing Pokemon Go with a new phone using the same account, will the data and/or Pokemon that I have caught be saved in my same account with a new phone? I feel really worried for losing everything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can link your account by signing in with the same Google account or Pokemon Trainer Account.

**Your progress will be automatically synced**, so need to worry about losing your hard-earned pokemon!